# Filtering navigation property in eager loading with NHibernate with LINQ

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-entities

I use this in EF

```
 var users = Context.CreateSet<User>()
             .Select(u => new {
                               User = u,
                               Salary = u.Salaries.Where(s => !s.Deleted)
                              })
                              .AsEnumerable()
                              .Select(a => a.User);
```

There is a Linq way to do this in NHibernate and i want it work for navigation property load by lazy load too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate will not fill the collection with filtered results this way and it is not a good idea because you get a broken model. The best options i see

```
var users = session.Query<User>()
    .Fetch(u => u.Salaries)
    .Select(u => new
    {
        User = u,
        ActiveSalaries = u.Salaries.Where(s => !s.Deleted)
    });
```

or

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Salary> ActiveSalaries
{
    get { return Salaries.Where(s => !s.Deleted); }
}

var users = session.Query<User>()
    .Fetch(u => u.Salaries)
```

or

```
// ctor
ActiveSalaries = Salaries.Where(s => !s.Deleted);

// property
public virtual IEnumerable<Salary> ActiveSalaries { get; private set; }


// mapping almost same as that of Salaries
HasMany(x => x.ActiveSalaries).Table("Salaries").Where("Deleted=0");

var users = session.Query<User>()
    .Fetch(u => u.ActiveSalaries);
```